# Can an undirected graph with n vertices and n - 1 edges not be connected?

Tags: graph, undirected-graph

I know that for an undirected graph with n vertices the minimum number of edges it must have for it to be connected is n - 1. However, if a graph has n vertices and n - 1 edges, is it always connected?

Answer (score 3):

no thats not the case, example:

[image]